# How to find a polynomial that satisfies $p(x+1)-p(x)=x^2$ subject to $p(0)=0$?

Tags: polynomials

> How to find a polynomial that satisfies $p(x+1)-p(x)=x^2$ subject to $p(0)=0$?

I tried to take $p(X)$ as a second degree polynomial but it didn't work, what should I do?

Comment: Note that if $p(x) $ is of degree $n$ then $p(x+1)-p(x)$ is of degree $n-1$ and hence you should look for a cubic polynomial $p(x) $ whose constant term is $0$ as $p(0)=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. One may try
$$
p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
$$ obtaining
$$
p(x+1)-p(x)=3 a x^2+(3 a+2 b) x+a + b + c
$$ Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

$p (1)-p (0)=0^2 \\\  p(2)-p (1)=1^2 \\\ ... \\\ p (k+1)-p (k)=k^2. \\\ $

Add equations together giving

$-p (0)+p (k+1)=0^2+1^2 + \cdots + k^2 \\\ $

I think it can be taken from here by you.

Comment: Just in case the OP doesn't get it: we have $1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + k^2 = \frac {k (k+1) (2k+1)} 6$, so $p(k) = \frac {(k-1) k (2k-1)} 6$ (because $p(0) = 0$), which can be achieved if we take $p(x) = \frac {(x-1) x (2x-1)} 6$. This is the best answer among the ones currently given, and it's a shame that it is not more upvoted and accepted.

Comment: While the other answer is more general, I think this answer deserves +1 for being very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

i am just going another approach : As $p(0)=0$ , one also has $p(1)-p(0)=0$ , so $p(1)=0$. Hence both $0, 1$ are roots of $p(x)$ . So $P(x)=Kx(x-1)q(x)$ , where k is a non-zero constant and $q(x)$ is a non-zero polynomial ( possible constant ) .